# Analysis I- Show $ \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R_+}\quad\sqrt[n]{x+y} \leq \sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{y} $

Tags: analysis

Show:
$$
\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R_+}\quad\sqrt[n]{x+y} \leq \sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{y}
$$

As I've said in a different post, I'm new to Analysis (two weeks), and I have this question that I'm not sure how to answer.

Should I do that with proof by negating? Or something a like?
I also would like not to get the full answer at first and just a hit to aim me what I should think about.

Comment: I have seen your posts on yesterday too. It seems to me that, you are unable to proceed on how to solve such problems. So, my suggestion for you is to understand the problem before solving it. Any given problem, will always be given basing on some well known formulae, or logically based steps. You need to understand them carefully and then start solving.

Comment: I don't have any idea for now, but there are a plenty of books online which could really help you. Mathematics is really beautiful, hope you understand that.

Comment: I still cannot understand how an answer should look like in Analysis.

Comment: They can be solved in various ways. The best way is ofcourse the one which looks the most elegant. Practicing more problems and understanding their applications will teach you how to produce elegant proofs.

Comment: Im used to it being some mathematical calculation and then a clear answer such X equals something

Answer (score 1):

Here's a approach using binomial theorem.

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then the conditions are sufficient to apply the binomial theorem.
Which states that,
$$(x+y)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^{k}$$
Replace $x,y$ with $x^{\frac{1}{n}}, y^{\frac{1}{n}}$.
$$(\sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{y})^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{1-\frac{k}{n}}y^{\frac{k}{n}}$$
Observe the cases when $k=0$ and $k=n$.
$$\sum_{0<k<n}x^{1-\frac{k}{n}}y^{\frac{k}{n}}+x+y$$
Note that summation term is atleast $0$ and tends to $\infty$ as n increases.
Which implies that,
$$(\sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{y})^{n}\ge (x+y)$$
$$(\sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{y})\ge (x+y)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Proving the required claim

Answer (score 0):

You can start by the square roots and apply the indication given in the comments :
raise each side to the power 2, expand and conclude.

Do it then with the cubic roots, and conclude with the same method.

Then the comment gives the general method.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Why to the power of 2 and not to the power of n ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to use derivatives.

First, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we get the equality if one of the variables is zero, so we safely can assume that $x$, $y\neq 0$. Observe that your inequality is equivalent to prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have
\begin{align*}
    1\leq \sqrt[n]{u}+\sqrt[n]{1-u},\ u\in (0, 1).
\end{align*}
This equivalence is obtained by *normalization*: divide your inequality by $\sqrt[n]{x+y}$ and then consider the change of variables $u=x/(x+y)$, which allows us to 'reduce' the dimension of the problem (this can be done due to the homogeneous role played by $x$ and $y$ in the inequality). If we prove that for $u\in (0, 1)$ the function $f: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by
\begin{align*}
    f(n)=\sqrt[n]{u}+\sqrt[n]{1-u}
\end{align*}
is increasing, we can deduce that $f(n)\geq f(1)=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and we are done.

The function $f$ is well-defined for all $u\in (0, 1)$, and we can safely consider $f$ as function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Computing the derivative of $f$
\begin{align*}
    f'(n)&=-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\left(u^{1/n}\log(u)+(1-u)^{1/n}\log(1-u)\right)\\
    &=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\left(u^{1/n}\log(\tfrac{1}{u})+(1-u)^{1/n}\log(\tfrac{1}{1-u})\right)\\
    &\geq 0
\end{align*}
since $1/u>1$ and $1/(1-u)>1$. Hence $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing, and so is $f$ restricted to $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Without a loss of generality, assume $x \leq y$ and $0 \leq \frac{x}{y} \leq 1$.

By Bernoulli's inequality
\begin{align*}
(1 + m)^r &\leq 1 + rm, \hspace{3ex} 0\leq r\leq1, m\geq-1\\
(x+y)^\frac{1}{n} = y^\frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{x}{y}\right)^\frac{1}{n}&\leq y^\frac{1}{n}\left(1 + \frac{x}{yn}\right) = y^\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}xy^{\frac{1}{n} - 1}\end{align*}
It's all about comparing that last term to $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

> \begin{align*}\frac{1}{n}xy^{\frac{1}{n} - 1} &= x^\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}x^{1-\frac{1}{n}}y^{\frac{1}{n} - 1}\right)\\&= x^\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\right)\\&\leq x^\frac{1}{n}\end{align*}

Hence $(x+y)^\frac{1}{n} \leq x^\frac{1}{n} + y^\frac{1}{n}$.